# How to get access to the values of descendent nodes

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have the following xml file, trying to modify the values in every node e.g. the property "client".

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<report>
  <feature tag="Config"/>
  <feature tag="Runtime">
    <feature tag="Metadata">
      <property name="date" type="date" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="01.01.1970"/>
      <property name="time" type="time" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="00:00:00"/>
      <property name="client" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="IBM Engineering Lifecycle Optimization - Publishing"/>
     </feature>
  <feature tag="Output">
 <feature tag="Log"/>
<feature tag="Templates">
```

I tried the following code, to get access to the nodes. The Problem is, that this code only detects the 'report' node but not the nodes with 'feature tag="name"'.

In my opinion, this is not standard XML and this is the reason, why the named tags are not detected with their names.

Is there a possibility to get access to the 'feature tags' by their names?

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(filename)

        For Each xName As XElement In doc.Descendants("report")
            
        'From here I tried in the debugger to get access to one of the named tags, but without success

        Next xName
```

Comment: Please correct your xml to be valid xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is unclear, the XML invalid...
So this is just a WAG,

```
    Dim doc As XElement
    ' doc = XElement.Load(filename)
    'FOR TEST - use literal
    doc = <report>
              <feature tag="Config"/>
              <feature tag="Runtime"/>
              <feature tag="Metadata">
                  <property name="date" type="date" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="01.01.1970"/>
                  <property name="time" type="time" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="00:00:00"/>
                  <property name="client" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="IBM Engineering Lifecycle Optimization - Publishing"/>
              </feature>
              <feature tag="Output"/>
              <feature tag="Log"/>
              <feature tag="Templates"/>
          </report>

    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    ie = doc.Descendants 'all elements

    ie = doc.Elements 'top level elements

    ' <property> element with an attribute name = client
    ie = From el In doc...<property>
            Where el.@name = "client"
            Select el

    ' <feature> element with an attribute tag = Metadata
    ie = From el In doc...<feature>
            Where el.@tag = "Metadata"
            Select el
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely to be that the XML quoted is not valid, it is missing multiple closing tags. Here is an example of how your XML might need to look:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<report>
    <feature tag="Config"/>
    <feature tag="Runtime"/>
    <feature tag="Metadata">
        <property name="date" type="date" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="01.01.1970"/>
        <property name="time" type="time" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="00:00:00"/>
        <property name="client" editable="false" visible="true" required="false" value="IBM Engineering Lifecycle Optimization - Publishing"/>
    </feature>
    <feature tag="Output"/>
    <feature tag="Log"/>
    <feature tag="Templates"/>
</report>
```

Perhaps use an online validation tool such as the one at https://freeonlineformatter.com/xml-validator to check your code.

Comment: The onlinevalidator says "valid xml", so the reason has to be something different.

Comment: The xml in this answer is valid , but the xml in the question is not